# How to write the argument of a function in the terminal with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, console, arguments

I'm using this code to connect to mailchimp API, get a list of members and put all their email adresses in an array:

```
var mailchimpMarketing = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimpMarketing.setConfig({
  apiKey: "MY API KEY",
  server: "MY SERVER",
});


async function getArrayEmailMembersFromMailchimpListID(listID){
  const response = await mailchimpMarketing.lists.getListMembersInfo(listID);
  const emailsMailchimp = response.members.map(member => member.email_address);
  console.log(emailsMailchimp)
  return emailsMailchimp;
}
getArrayEmailMembersFromMailchimpListID("MY LIST ID")
```

My problem is that I want to write the list ID `"MY LIST ID"` in my terminal and not in my code when I'm starting the script. Something like that:

```
$node test.js MyListID
```

Instead of

```
$node test.js
```

But I don't know how to do it.

I think it's possible with `process.argv` or `minimist` but I don't understand how they work. Can someone explain it to me or is their any other possibility ?

Comment: You can look for npm module "yargs" it should suite your use-case

Comment: I tried but I'm using node v8.9.4 and it's only available on node v10

Comment: @SamyRharade What is stopping you from upgrading?

Comment: It's for my work and they are using this version, they don't want to change it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Node-JS v8.x [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/process.html#process_process_argv):

> The process.argv property returns an array containing the command line
> arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched. The first
> element will be process.execPath. See process.argv0 if access to the
> original value of argv[0] is needed. The second element will be the
> path to the JavaScript file being executed. The remaining elements
> will be any additional command line arguments.

So in your case you can simply do:

```
getArrayEmailMembersFromMailchimpListID(process.argv[2])
```

Of course you should add some error-handling for this to make it more robust.